# Filter trips between zones QGIS

Tags: qgis

Need ideas.

1. I have a  layer of city shapefile with zones:
   [image]
2. I have a layer with [FCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_car_data) data:

[image]

---

### My goal/question is:

Is it possible to define a model where I will be able to choose any 2 zone and get points **started** and **ended** (not just passed through(!)) between these 2 given zones?

For example: `id_easy` - `d1ed640cca` started and finished trip between given zones.

FCD data format (very small sample):

```
id_easy    ordinal  latitude    longitude   epoch             day_of_week   geometry
d1ed640cca       1  11.0589     3.6907      04-06-16 00:48    Saturday      POINT (3.6907 11.0589)
745b0999ce       1  11.0591     3.6911      04-06-16 00:40    Saturday      POINT (7.6911 11.0591)
```

Comment: Some more details on your intended output/further analysis, your workflow, possible automation, repetition and scripting would be helpful. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by started and ended in those zones? A point is either inside a polygon or it's not. Are you creating routes between polygons, and you want the points at the start and end of each route?